# How to find specific value from MySQL json(or text) column?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

How to find specific value from MySQL json(or text) column?  Row example:

```
'profile': [{'name':['John', 'Smith'], 'interest':['Sports', 'Games']}]
```

in above example, **I want to search 'John' or 'Sports' without specifying key**('name' or interests).  MySQL official guide says you have to specify column name, but in my case it's preferred not to choose column name.

Another question is search performance if there are hundreds of thousands of rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JSON_SEARCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function in MySQL 5.7 and later. It returns the path within the JSON document to the value you're searching for:

```
mysql> set @j = '{"profile": [{"name":["John", "Smith"], "interest":["Sports", "Games"]}]';

mysql> select json_search(@j, 'one', 'John') as path;
+------------------------+
| path                   |
+------------------------+
| "$.profile[0].name[0]" |
+------------------------+
```

But I recommend using normal columns instead of JSON if you need to search for values. In other words, you shouldn't ever reference a JSON column in the `WHERE` clause of a query.

In this case, you should have tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 first_name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE profile_interests (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 profile_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 interest VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
);
```

Then search using queries for the column you want.

P.S.:  I fixed the quotes in your JSON document. You used single quotes like `'` but you must use double quotes like `"` for it to be valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution - use fulltext search in MySQL that json string can be searched with keywords.